# Single, company wide test overview

Tags: testing, reporting

We have a number of projects that integrate with each other (e.g. frontend, backend) as well as a separate project to do the complex, integrated testing. Are there any tools that can take e.g. junit xml or cucumber json and combine them into a single report for the team / company?